# JNI std::vector<uint8_t> to jbyteArray

Tags: java-native-interface

`std::vector<uint8_t>`  converting to `jbyteArray`

I currently have jbyteArray converted to std::vector<uint8_t>:

```
auto byteBuffer = new jbyte[env->GetArrayLength(byteArray)];
env->GetByteArrayRegion(byteArray, 0, env->GetArrayLength(byteArray), byteBuffer);

std::vector<uint8_t> retVector(byteBuffer, byteBuffer + env->GetArrayLength(byteArray));
```

I just have to go in reverse and my brain is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NewByteArray` and `SetByteArrayRegion`. I.e. something like this:

```
// vec is a std::vector<uint8_t>

const jsize len = static_cast<jsize>(vec.size());
jbyteArray java_array = env->NewByteArray(len);
env->SetByteArrayRegion(java_array, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<const jbyte*>(vec.data()));
return java_array;
```